# How to quickly temporarly remove elements from DOM and return them on demand?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I want to ask, how to deal with many elements on the page that are aranged like this:

```
<div id="tab1">
  ... hundreds of <div>'s
</div>
<div id="tab2">
  ... hundreds of <div>'s
</div>
etc...
```

Those hundred's of divs are loaded using AJAX on demand. Problem is, that there is more tabs, each holding large number of elements in DOM which makes all operations slower and slower as more tabs are loaded with content.

Is there an easy way how to temporarly remove elements from invisible tabs and return them on demand when certain tab is clicked to be visible ?

Of course I don't want to use `$('#tab1 .content').hide();` because it would only make this tab's content invisible, but content would be still in DOM.

Thanks for any help in advance.

**EDIT**: I want to reuse previously fetched(cached) content. So no repeated AJAX calls would be needed for reopening one of the previously opened tabs.

Comment: Dont load everything on page-load - just the tabs (maybe a separate call to figure how many tabs you need and their names) - then on click - AJAX call to load that specific tab content

Comment: Have you tried jquery `.remove()`

Comment: you might wanna have a look at e.g. [angular.js](https://angularjs.org/) or [Backbone](http://backbonejs.org/).

Comment: See my edit. I want to reuse previously fetched content. So no `.remove()` or repeated AJAX calls fit my need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several solutions to what you are trying to do.

Omar's solution works, but it has some draw backs -- any attached event handlers get lost. Delegated event handlers can deal with the situation...

Another option, more pure Javascript, would be to create a document fragment and then move all the tabbed elements into the fragment to be put back.

```
var tab1 = document.getElementById("tab1");
var frag1 = document.createDocumentFragment();
while (tab.firstChild) {
  frag1.appendChild(tab.firstChild);
}

// At this point, all the elements will be in `frag` -- in reverse order.
// Not an issue -- just reverse the loop to put everything back.
```

**EDIT**

```
var tab1 = document.getElementById("tab1");
while (frag1.firstChild) {
  tab1.appendChild(frag1.firstChild);
}
```

Comment: Could you please update your answer with code snippet how to put content back ? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily dot it  with jquery

```
tab1=$("#tab1").html();
```

To Remove it  `$("#tab1").html("");`
to reload Again `$("#tab1").html(tab1)`